# Is there a way to tell apart from user based changes to model and ones that came from the database?

Tags: backbone.js

I would like to trigger auto save on my model every time something changes, but only if the change came from the UI (i.e. the view). I mean, if the change came from the database, then there is no point in saving it again, it just came from the database...

However `fetch` and `save` can trigger `change` events (`fetch` because it brings potentially different state of the model, and `save` as it can bring the `id` for a newly created model)

So in the `change` event, I'd like to know what caused the change.

e.g. was it a call from the view?:

```
this.model.set("foo", "bar"); //triggers a change event as foo's value changed
```

Or a result of a sync operation?:

```
model.fetch(); //triggers a change event as the model changed in the DB
model.save(); //triggers a change event as the id was empty
```

Is there a way to tell them apart?

Once solution I thought of is wrapping view calls to the model's `set` with a `setAttribute` method, and triggering a custom `changeDueToUIAction` event, but I'm sure this has been solved before and I'm sure in a better way...

Or am I missing something altogether and the problem is that I ask the wrong question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say there are several custom solutions involving more or less boilerplate. And there is an easy one, though still adding a bit of boilerplate.
(Without any major change to Backbone) you can't know the source of the change (thinking about it, how would you have access to it in the *Model#set* method?). What you have access to in a listener is 2 objects. First one is the model which was changed. Second is the options you passed when calling the set method. So I guess you could do something like that:

```
// in the view
this.model.set('foo', 'bar', {'isFromUI': true});

// in your model
this.listenTo(this, 'change', function(model, flags) {
  if(flags && flags.isFromUI) this.save();
});
```

Comment: didn't use arguments[1], simply declared the variable in the function (the first is the mode, the second is our param, the rest of the code is the same) - but this is exactly the solution I wanted, thanks!

Comment: @EranMedan I know, that's just plain basic JS anyway, I just didn't want to bother giving names to the vars.

Comment: Yep, do you mind if I edit it to reflect the way I eventually used it? It might be clearer to future readers new to JavaScript (though I would really like to think most JS devs know what `arguments` is, but I've met a few who don't)

Comment: Appreciate it & thanks for a great answer, saved me a lot of time